# Changing grub purple interface to CLI

Tags: boot, grub2

I want to see all everything in booting like what is being loaded and all instead of grub purple Interface.. So is there any way to enable text kind of mode and disable that purple screen ??

Comment: If you press any arrow key(at the time of booting or shutting down) then your purple screen will change and will show you all the processes which are starting..

Comment: yeah thanks , its so simple but am new with it..

Answer (score 2):

### Permanent

Type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. Look for the line that reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vesafb.invalid=1 splash quiet"
```

remove the `splash quiet` part (yours might be different, so don't change anything but that). Save the file.

Now type `sudo update-grub`. Reboot, no more purple screen.

### Temporal (one time)

In the boot menu, press <kbd>E</kbd>. Look at the end of the line starting with `linux` for `splash quiet`. Remove `splash quiet` (do not touch anything else) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. No purple screen.

Comment: we cant change background in grub as we can do in berg??

Comment: @Sushantp606 ask that in another question....